# How can i make a low poly flame animation in Blender

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

[image: here's the example i found online]

my computer is not exactly advanced and i really need some low memory usage SFX that can be exported quite easily for the game engine without many memory leak.
(and yes if you want to ask what game engine i use to make games it is Godot Game Engine)
i would really appreciate it if there's anyone that can give me some clue or maybe made some tutorial for me (wishful thinking intensifies) or maybe pitch in some idea if you don't know any method for this problem.

Thank you :D

Comment: I expect a particle fire [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FLiJp__oYA) would also work in godot.

Comment: I remember once seeing someone use metaballs with a forcefield to do something similar. But it was a still fire for a poster and they converted the metaballs to a mesh then sculpted it a bit.

Comment: @sambler yes it could work but it's not 'suitable' for the stylized design that i based it, and would look quite if you might say out of place (imagine it like using a charcoal to finish a watercolor painting)

Comment: @eromod thank you for the idea! I would try to experiment on it for a bit :D.    Thank you all for the idea and notification though really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you want a rendered Sprite, or an animated mesh for Godot

Comment: @zachman both, because i will use the technique to create quite a few SFX (though it would be quite helpful if someone could show me the 'proper' way to do both :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick stab at this with a Sculpted mesh using Dynotopo symmetry off with a pixel setting of 12.

The rest was done with just animating an empty, and using that empty as the referenced object in a displacement modifier with a magic texture.

This was about 10 minutes worth of work if you happen to be efficient in Blender.

Hence I'm sure you could spend a little more time if you want it to look as good as it does in your reference.

I would imagine that an animated loop of upward flying diamond shapes at the same speed and the same material would sell the flying ember effect.

Here's the fruit of my 10 minutes (the difference between the two are texture selection & empty animation differences only):

Attempt #1:
[image]

Attempt #2:
[image]

---

Per request here is the Blend File:
I've also included an action within it for you associated to a "Fake" user.
As of Right now, the animation wont start until you hit frame 15.
In the NLA editor just drag the action back to the beginning frame (highlight it and hit <kbd>G</kbd> >> Drag to the left) to watch the full animation from the start.

As for a sprite sheet, I really recommend watching the video I linked to in the comments.

Here is a Sprite sheet that I rendered out from this file:

[image: Torch Sprite]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! :D, can you upload the blend file for further study

Comment: Thank you!, can you upload the blend file for further study and can you describe how to pack the animation (be it sprite or animated mesh for further completion and to any blender user that have difficulty in this regard). :D (sorry for double posting i'm writing on my android and it's slow as hell)

Comment: @noob.blenderhead For the animation packing, I would imagine that you would have to follow steps similar to [THESE](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/387170/how-can-we-export-blender-animations-to-unity-4-.html). For the Sprite Sheet side of things, [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSVwtVir5fM) is how I handle it when I make mine, because the old Blender Spritify plug-in doesn't seem to work for me anymore. These two items are either slightly or altogether off-topic, as they relate to both Unity, & Gimp respectively, so I'll leave them here for you in the comments. As for the blend, g

Comment: ... As for the blend give me a few, and I will get it appended to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the complementary .blend file i've managed to make my own low poly esque flame that actually fit the design style i'm working on ! :D
(here's the file for anyone wondering what kind of artstyle i'm adopting.)
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1524/
p.s :i will keep this question n answer session open so anyone who's happen to have some trouble as i have can get some idea and help they happen to need.

Comment: That's a pretty good looking styled flame.